# Saving AddressbookUI address.text to Documents directory for use in InApp email

Tags: iphone, email, addressbook

I was trying recycle code for saving an image and attaching it to an email, with no luck. After I get the three values out of the PeoplepickerNavigation controller I want to save them for use and place them as text into an email. All I get now is a placed image called "addresssend" in my email body, how would I extract the text from the "addresssend" file so that the user would see firstName, lastname, & address.

Here is the saving code:

```
- (IBAction)saveData {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedDataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"addresssend.txt"];
NSString *addresssend = lastName.text; // lastName is from the LastNameProperty
[addresssend writeToFile:savedDataPath atomically:NO];  
}
```

Here is the retrieving code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"addresssend.txt"];
NSData *myData2 = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile2] autorelease];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData2 mimeType:@"text/txt" fileName:@"addresssend"];
```

I can see how this would just deposit the file, can anyone point me in the right direction so that the email body shows the actual name & address?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a search for MFMailComposeViewController and take a look as some of the tutorials. You've asked a bunch of related questions that could be answered by doing a Google search for the component.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO]; 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: Thanks, the retrieving code is within the MFMailViewController, however it's just bringing up the file..I'm looking for the contents of the file to be displayed.